# Escape double quote character in string representing a sql query

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use a string to represent a SQL query in VB. i.e.

```
dim sSql As string
sSql = "SELECT thing FROM example where xml NOT LIKE '%<FUNDED YESNO=""YES"">%'"
```

The problem is that when this is passed to SQL it seems to be passing the double quotes which I've used to escape here **YESNO=""YES""** which causes issues.

What is the proper way to escape these double quotes? I've tried

```
sSql = "SELECT thing FROM example where xml NOT LIKE '%<FUNDED YESNO=" & Chr(34) & "YES" & Chr(34) & ">%'
```

to no avail.

Comment: `which causes issues`... what issues? Is there any error message? Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: That's not possible. The `String` only contains one double-quote. The extra double-quote is simply a literal representation, much like a backslash in a C# literal. How exactly are you determining that this appears to be the case?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm stepping through the code using visual studio and working out what the value of sSql is when it's passed

Comment: @TangoKilo That's just what the debugger shows. Try logging it to a file and then reading the file.

Comment: Use parameters. What kind of database are you connecting to (ex: mySQL, SQL Server, ...)?

Comment: Note that the debug watch window will show strings with escapes in the same format as the language under debug.  If you want to see it otherwise, you'll need to use the viewer that opens when you click on the magnifying glass icon in the watch.

Comment: Any representation of that `String` that wraps it in double-quotes will escape the double-quotes within it. Like i said though, that is just a representation of literal text. If you look at it as text rather than a literal `String` then you'll see that. If you look at the `Length` of the `String` you'll see that those extra double-quote characters are not included in the count because they are not part of the `String`. Etc, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd tend to use a parameterized query for this anyway:

```vb
Dim Sql As string = "SELECT thing FROM example where xml NOT LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'"
Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000).Value = "<FUNDED YESNO=""YES"">"
    cn.Open()

    ' ...
End Using
```

I ***promise*** the string used for the match will end up looking like this:

`<FUNDED YESNO="YES">`

Parameterized queries tend to side-step this kind of issue, anyway, and they are very important for avoiding SQL injection bugs and attacks.

Now you can also easily refactor this code out to a method where you can send any search key you want.

Comment: Using a parameter isn't solving any problem here. The value is hard-coded and you have to escape the double-quotes whether they are in a literal for the SQL code or a literal for the parameter value. Using parameters is good for variable values and especially user input but this is neither. At least, what's shown in the question is neither. Maybe that's not representative of the real code though.